# Arima antipersistence

Tags: persistence, arima

I’m running RStudio Version 1.1.419 with R-3.4.3 on Windows 10. I am trying to fit an (f)arima model and setting the fractional differencing parameter during the optimization process to be between (-0.5,0.5), i.e. allowing for antipersistence (d < 0), short memory (d = 0) and long memory (d > 0). I have tried multiple functions to accomplish that. I am aware that the default of fracdiff$drange is (0,0.5). Therefore this ...

```
> result <- fracdiff(MeanPrice, nar = 2, nma = 1, drange = c(-0.5,0.5))
```

sadly returns this..

```
Warning: C fracdf() optimization failure
Warning message: unable to compute correlation matrix; maybe change 'h'
```

Is there a way to fit fracdiff or other models (maybe arfima::arfima()?) with that drange? Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fracdiff/fracdiff.pdf), it states that the `h` argument for `fracdiff` "is used to compute a finite difference approximation to the Hessian, and
hence only influences the cov, cor, and std.error computations."  However, as they are referring to the Hessian, I would assume that this affects the results of the MLE.  There are other functions in that package that may be helpful:  `fdGHP` for estimating the order of fractional differencing based on the Geweke and Porter-Hudak method, and similarly `fdSperio.`

Take a look at the `forecast` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf).  If you estimate the order of fractional differencing using the above mentioned functions, you might be able to use the same method described in the details of the `arfima` function.